# How can I use overflow:hidden with a header tag

Tags: html, css

I want to keep the header in single line, as described below:

```css
h2 {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h2>
I want to keep the text of this header in single-line... the extra characters should be hidden
</h2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
h2 {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<h2>
I want to keep the text of this header in single-line... the extra characters should be hidden
</h2>
```

you can fix what width you want to hide the content behind

Comment: Thanks, is `width: 100%;` needed?

Comment: it depend on how long content you want to show .
In this case is one line . So i think 100% is ok.
You may set 100px , etc...

Answer (score 3):

You need a width and `white-space:nowrap;` for that:

```css
h1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1>This text is long. Way too long to be shown in one line. It even is that long</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks, is `width: 100%;` needed?

Comment: It may not be necessary in every case. But I would suggest to add a width that limits the `h1` to the max width of the surrounding element, to prevent it from stretching this element.